# Two GPU Setup - Only One GPU Works With Monitor

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, display, motherboard, gpu

I recently replaced the motherboard of my computer with a `Gigabyte X99-UD3P` model. Strangely, the new motherboard seems to use my top-most GPU when I boot a live USB, enter BIOS, or try to display on my monitor anything other than my Windows 10 installation, ignoring that my monitor is connected to the bottom GPU. This is a problem because my top-most GPU doesn't actually display an image on my monitor.

Compared to similar problems, I believe my situation is different, since both GPUs are detected but only one works.

I've tried to diagnose the problem, and haven't found the cause, although under system information I found there's a difference between the two GPUs:

[image: System Information Page]

Why might one GPU have no resolution, the other have no IO ports, and what can be done to fix the problem of the upper GPU not displaying to my monitor?

Answer (score 0):

As it would turn out, sometimes you need to try, and try again. I had reseated my GPU multiple times, and upon reseating it once more, the GPU worked. The hole to screw in the GPU was not aligned with the chassis, so what worked was carefully putting the screw in at an angle.